# Looking for 2 types of file extension

Tags: regex, bash

So I have this script that is suposed to run several commands on 2 specific types of files from various folders, the problem is:

The files I want to find file.**fa** or file.**fasta**

The files that exist among those file.**fa.amb** file.**fa.ann** file.**fa.bwt** file.**fa.pac** file.**fa.sa** file.**fasta.amb** file.**fasta.ann** file.**fasta.bwt** file.**fasta.pac** file.**fasta.sa**

Im doing a for loop something like this:

```
for i in path/path/file.fa*
do
   run command $i
done
```

How do I only pick up the files I want instead of all those files ?

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
for i in path/path/file.{fa,fasta}
do
   run command $i
done
```

Comment: Or file.fa{,sta}